# Instance of fractionnal int required, simple function

Tags: haskell, division

I want to to a simple Integer division, and I get this in Hugs

```
Hugs> :load prog.hs
ERROR file:prog.hs:30 - Instance of Fractional Int required for definition of lastf
```

My simple program goes like this

```
lastf::Int->Int
lastf 1 = 0 
lastf n = if even n then (2*n+1) else (n/2)
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I simply do a division ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do integer division, just use `div`:

```
lastf n = if even n then 2 * n + 1 else n `div` 2
```

The reason why is because `Int` does not implement the `/` operator, it is reserved for `Fractional` types, like `Float` and `Double`.  Obviously, if you do `3 / 2` and you want `1.5` back, you can't represent that as an `Int`, you'd have to use a `Float` or `Double` (or any type that implements the `Fractional` typeclass).

Comment: @maximegir It could also be written `div n 2`, the ``'s are just to make a function infix

Comment: That's only if you want to use it in infix notation.  You can also use it as `div n 2`.  This actually works for all functions that take 2 arguments: `(+1) \`map\` [1, 2, 3]` would return `[2, 3, 4]`, or `[1..3] \`zip\` [5,10..]` would return `[(1, 5), (2, 10), (3, 15)]`